# Need to convert rows into column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table in SQL:

```
ID  uniquecol   version

1   test        4.4.552.14          
2   test        4.4.554             
3   test        4.4.543.11
```

Need output like as below:

```
test, 1,2,3, 4.4.552.14,4.4.554, 4.4.543.11
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIQUECOL, LISTAGG(ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS COL2,
LISTAGG(VERSION,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS COL3
FROM t1
GROUP BY UNIQUECOL;
```

> Output -

```
UNIQUECOL   COL2    COL3
test        1,2,3   4.4.552.14,4.4.554,4.4.543.11
```

Comment: Thanks Shrek, But i am getting below error.
'LISTAGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
I am using SQL server 2005 and 2008 R2.

Also i want the output like, each cell to become one column. So in the above case, the output should be 7 columns. (test, 1,2,3, 4.x, 4.x,4.x)